# Unable to get form to submit with basic PHP and Bootstrap, validation working but no posting

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure this has been asked many times before, but being an amateur I could not get any of the others answers to work for my case.

This is the PHP form I'm including on the HTML page with the email removed

```
<?php
$nameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = $messageErr = "";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = "";

$to = "email@gmail.com";
$from = "email@site.com";

$headers = "From: $email \r\n";

$subject = "New submission";
$body = "New Loan Request: \n $message";

mail(to,from,subject,headers,body)

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phoneErr = "";
  } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $messageErr = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $website = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
  $comment = test_input($_POST["message"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

And the HTML of the form...The validation is working but I'm unable to get anything to post after submission or for a submission to the email address I'm using.

```
                  <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Scenario *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                              <div id="success"></div>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Send Message</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have a syntax error.

Right here

```
 mail(to,from,subject,headers,body)
```

Should be

```
 mail(to,from,subject,headers,body);
```

Missing Semi-colon.

I will ignore that none of your variables for the mail function call are correct either ... hint ... hint ... They are all missing the `$` ....  so yup, each of those will be a syntax error too.

It may be ... um ... informative to turn on error reporting

```
 <?php
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
     error_reporting(-1);
```

You will also find that validation works best if it's done before the email.  As it stands most of those `variables` ( if I can use the term loosely ) will have anything in them.

And this

```
  $name = $email = $phone = $message = "";
```

is weirding me out a bit.

***UPDATE***
Here I cleaned that up some in the way I would do it.

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

        $errors = [];
        $input = [];

        foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ){
            $value =  htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( trim($value) ) );

             switch( $key ){
                case 'submit': 
                    continue;  //ignore
                break; //break is not really needed here, but whatever ...
                // case 'email':  validate email etc.
                // break;
                default:
                    if( empty( $value ) ){
                        $errors[$key] = ucfirst( $key ).' is required.';
                    }else{
                        $input[$key] = $value;
                    }
                break; //break is not really needed here, but whatever ...
             } //end switch                     
        }//end foreach

        $to = "email@gmail.com";

        $headers = "From: {$input['email']} \r\n";
        $subject = "New submission";
        $body = "New Loan Request: \n {$message}";  //message is undefined

        if( empty( $erros ) ){
            mail($to,$input['from'],$subject,$headers,$body);
        }else{
            //do something with $errors
        }

    } //end if submit

    //?>
```

I never use ending PHP tags unless the file has HTML and PHP ( which mine never do ), closing tags are optional anyway.  Leaving them in can cause un-intended output, such as having a line return after the closing tag, which can be real annoying when doing file downloads.

But, that's just me and how I do it.  Someone else may tell you something different.

I made this example, just to show How much better using an array for this stuff is.  So think about later if you want to add in say address fields.  Like `street`, `zip`, `state`, `county`, `country` or what have you.

If you do these in a less automated fashion, your code will grow and grow and grow, because you have to add so much in for each field.  You'll be adding in 6 lines of code for each one, before you even use the data.  Using an array, you just add it into the switch statement if it has some special requirement.

I'm to lazy to be adding all that code in all the time ....

Comment: Your addition helped! It seems if I run it inline with the HTML it will work but not as a include_once function on the page. The message appeared without the message or email address but I may be able to tinker with that